# how to display data in json format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

hey actually i am new to node and angularjs and i am doing a project on node and angularjs i have a client and server node server is running on a port 3001 and client is running on 3000 whenever i run my server i will get a data in a json format but that data is not in a correct json format here is the data i am receiving from the server

```
color :
  white : &color-white "#FFFFFF"
  black : &color-black "#262626"
  neutral :
    20 : &color-neutral-20 "#222222"
     90 : &color-neutral-90 "#EEEEEE"
  blue:
    50: &color-blue-50 "#0000ff"
    90: &color-blue-60 "#3333ff"
  red:
    50: &color-red-90 "#ff0000"
    95: &color-red-90 "#ff8080"
  Green:
    40: &color-green "#00cc00"
    80: &color-green "#99ff99"
  Pink:
    80: &color-pink "#ff99cc"
    30: &color-pink "#ff0080"
  Yellow:
    70: &color-yellow "#ffff66"
    40: &color-yellow "#ffff00"

  border:
    brand: &color-border-brand "#1589ee"
    brand-dark: &color-border-brand-dark "#0070d2"
    customer: &color-border-customer "#ff9a3c"
    destructive: &color-border-destructive "#c23934"
    destructive-hover: &color-border-destructive-hover "#a61a14"


  interactive-color :
    default: *color-blue-50
    dark: *color-blue-60

  background-color :
    default : *color-white
    light : *color-neutral-90
    dark : *color-neutral-20
    disabled: *color-neutral-90

  text-color :
    default : *color-neutral-20
    on-light : *color-neutral-20
    on-dark : *color-white
    light : *color-neutral-20
    disabled : *color-neutral-20
    link :
      default : *color-blue-50
      on-dark : *color-white

font:
  family:
    text: &font-family-text "Salesforce Sans"
    heading: &font-family-heading "Arial"

  weight:
    light: &font-weight-light "300"
    regular: &font-weight-light "300"
    bold: &font-weight-light "300"

  size:
    xx-small: &font-size-text-xx-small ".625rem FONT_SIZE_1 10px"
    x-small: &font-size-text-x-small ".75rem FONT_SIZE_2 12px"
    small: &font-size-text-small ".8125rem FONT_SIZE_3 13px"
    medium: &font-size-text-medium ".1rem FONT_SIZE_5 16px"
    large: &font-size-text-large "1.125rem FONT_SIZE_6 18px"
    x-large: &font-size-text-x-large "1.25rem FONT_SIZE_7 20px"

  line-height:
    heading: &line-height-heading "1.25"
    text: &line-height-text "1.5"
    reset: &line-height-reset "1"
    tab: &line-height-tab "2.5rem 40px"
    button: &line-height-button "1.875rem 30px"
    button-small: &line-height-button-small "1.75rem 28px"

space :
  default : 16px
  xxs: 2px
  xs: 4px
  s: 8px
  m: 16px
  l: 32px
  xl: 64px
  inset :
    default : 16px 16px 16px 16px
    xxs : 2px 2px 2px 2px
    xs : 4px 4px 4px 4px
    s : 8px 8px 8px 8px
    m : 16px 16px 16px 16px
    l : 32px 32px 32px
```

i need to display this data in client side like design token format for ex color-blue, color-white, color-black etc
here is my angularjs code to receive the out put

```
angular.module('design',[]).controller('designController', 
function($scope,$http)
{
$scope.message="hii";
console.log(":outside");
$http.get('http://rest-
service.guides.spring.io/greeting').then(function(response)
{
console.log("inside");
$scope.greeting = Json.stringify(response.data);

});
});
```

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
<script 
src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js">
</script>

</head>
<body ng-app="design" class="container">
<br/>
<br />
<br />

<div class="row" style="background-color:purple;">
<font color="white">ellucian University</font>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<font color="purple">Design Tokens</font>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8" align="right">
 <input type="button"class="btn btn-primary" value="download" />
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
</div>
<br/>
<br/>

</div>
<div ng-controller="designController" class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <font color="purple">Tokens</font><br/>
 <li ng-repeat = "item in greeting track by $index">
 {{item}}
 </li>
 </body>
 </html>
```

please help me with this

Comment: If I understand, your problem is that you are not able to remove the junk from the JSON response to show the correct data in your client side?

Comment: yes i need to remove those junks but i dont know how to remove those junks f

Comment: What? Did you really look at the string? It is not JSON at all, not the slightest, not even close. It is some string containing some characters that are also contained in a JSON string. Nothing more

Comment: @devnull69 right, its not json format.

Comment: actually in a server side i have a file in .yml format that .yml file converted in to json so this is the result of yml file that converted in to json

Comment: It is not JSON. What did you use to convert to this format?

Comment: load : function() {
  
var data = fs.readFileSync('edit0.yml','utf8');
return data;
}

Comment: and in app.js app.get('/Tokens', function(req, res) {
  var TYPE=process.env.TYPE;

  var store=DesignFactory.storeDesign(TYPE);
  var data=store.load();
  res.end(JSON.stringify(data));

});

Comment: Oh you need to do your basics. You cannot just turn a random string into a JSON string. JSON.stringify will turn a Javascript object literal into a JSON string. That's it.

Comment: in first function i am reading yaml file  and returning data to app.js and i am converting that yaml file into json using JSON.stringify((data))

Comment: for my knowledge i know only one method to convert the string into json is JSON.stringify() so thats why i have used it please u help me how to convert that yml file in to json in a correct format

Comment: There is no "out of the box" way to convert this to JSON. You need to make up a way for yourself and then convert it manually.

Comment: And by the way: JSON.stringify is not at all about converting a string to JSON. It is about converting a Javascript object literal into it's JSON string notation.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a Yaml file.

What you need to do is read it, interpret it to a JS object, then converting this JS Object to a JSON that you can send.

```
'use strict';

const yaml = require('js-yaml'),
    fs = require('fs');


Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('your/yaml/file.yaml', (error, data) => {
            if(error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}).then((data) => {
    let doc = yaml.safeLoad(data);
    return Promise.resolve(doc);
}).then((doc) => {
    let json = JSON.stringify(doc);
    console.log('JSON: ' + json);
    return Promise.resolve();
}).then(() => {
    console.log('OK');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
});
```